# Usage of HashCodeBuilder in Hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I'd like to use Apache commons HashCodeBuilder and EqualsBuilder for overriding hashCode() and equals() method in POJO's. As per [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode) the identifier value should not be a part of hashCode method. In such a case, I won't be able to use Apache's builders as they would include the identifier value too.

What should I do? IDE's like intelliJ generate the hashCode functions but I don't want to depend on them. Is there any other library I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reflectionHashCode` method has [a variant which allows you to specify excluded fields](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html#reflectionHashCode%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Collection%29). As does [reflectionEquals](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Collection%29). They should help.